# How to place multiple imports in a single line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is about how to place multiple imports in a single line.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
```

Can we modify the above statements into a single statement like the one shown below:

```
from sys,os.path import argv,exists
```

Can we do it that way..?Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thankfully, you can't do that.

Comment: It doesnt even read very logically or cleanly anyways. You can do basic import x,z but not multiple selective imports

Comment: Why would you want to? is there a specific problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, you can't. Sorry!

The python [`import` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) only supports *one* module to import statements from at a time.

If you *could* do this, hypothetically speaking, what would the following mean:

```
from threading, multiprocessing import Thread, Condition, Lock
```

what module would `Condition` be imported from? Both modules define such a class.

Python prefers explicit over implicit; you select one source from which to import at a time as that results in the least surprise and the greatest clarity as to what is happening.

Answer (score 6):

```
from sys import argv; from os.path import exists
```

Comment: Just use newlines already; PEP-8 frowns upon the semicolon with cause.. "Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged."

Comment: @Martijn Pieter - I don't like it either, but it is legal.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the two lines on one and separate them with a semicolon, but other than that, no.

Answer (score 0):

If you had tried it you would see it does not work.  No, you can't do that.