# Writing list of import modules in a separate .py file

Tags: python, import

I have a long list of import modules, something like this:

```
import x
import y
.
.
```

How can I write these all imports in one line? I come from C programming and see people doing #include "all_lib.h".
Is there a equivalent or better pythonic way of doing this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10972075/4928322

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put all those imports in one python file, call it `all_imports.py`, and then import everything from that file using `from all_imports import *` in your actual Python file.

Example:

File `all_imports.py`

```
import math
import collections
```

File `test.py`

```
from all_imports import *

print dir()
print math.pi
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have a file, e.g., myimports.py containing all import modules and then use it as `from myimports import *`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from all_imports import *`. But using names not explicitly named in the module would not be pythonic according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) (under wildcards).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do

```
import x, y
```

But you shouldn't do it according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do:

```
import a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
```

But take a look at the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) which says that you shall put them on separate lines.